# Protractor throws "Invalid session Id" when you have browser.quit in afterAll block

Tags: selenium, protractor

I have two specs in a suite. Each spec has "browser.quit()" in afterAll block.
When I run these specs as suite, first spec execute without any issue and other spec throws "Invalid session ID" exception. How to fix this issue?.

Sample script.

test1.js & test2.js are same as below

```
describe("test1",function(){   
     beforeAll(function(){
         console.log("Pre-condition");
     });

     it("test1 scenario",function(){
        browser.waitForAngualrEnabled(false);
        browser.get("https://www.google.com");
     });

     afterAll(function(){ 
        browser.quit();
     });

    });
```

Protractor version : 7.0.0

### conf.js

```
exports.config={
  framework:'jasmine',
  directConnect: false,
  suites:{
  test:["test1.js","test2.js"]
  }
}
```

When these specs are run individually, it executes without any issues. I need each spec in suite has to  launch and quit browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why are you surprised about this error, if your script is:

- `console.log("Pre-condition");`
- `browser.waitForAngualrEnabled(false);`
- `browser.get("https://www.google.com");`
- `browser.quit(); // close browser!!!` <------------------
- run spec 2, but the browser is closed at this time

Don't close the browser after the spec 1 is completed

Comment: Not possible to start a new browser session after each spec in a suite?